# Доступ к файлам в WEB-INF не работает

Tags: java, mvc, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Есть следующая иерархия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конфигурации запуска контекст приложения задан как `/`. В свою же очередь URL получается `http://localhost:8080/`. По какой причине я до сих пор могу получить доступ к страничкам jsp в директории view прямо по URL, например: `http://localhost:8080/register.jsp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением является всего-лишь прописать в пути возвращаемой страницы часть путь WEB-INF: `/WEB-INF/view/category.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

> По какой причине я до сих пор могу получить доступ к страничкам jsp в директории view

Дело в том, что `WEB-INF` - это защищённая директория на сервере, доступ к файлам извне невозможен. Приложение может хранить свои файлы в этой директории, чтобы быть уверенным, которые недоступны для пользователей. Это в первую очередь относится к файлам конфигурации, и другим внутренним файлам. Туда же стали ложить JSP файлы в некоторых MVC фреймворках, чтобы ограничить прямой доступ к View, минуя контроллер. В сервлетах, которые реализуют MVC паттерн, используя диспетчер, то же самое. Поскольку эти JSP не могут работать без инициализации на контроллере, то прямой доступ к таким страницам будет вызывать исключения.

Comment: Я не очень разобрался в Вашем ответе. Все как Вы и написали, я не должен иметь возможность получать доступ к страницам по URL, например: http://localhost:8080/register.jsp. Но, если я попробую это сделать, то страница все равно откроется, хотя она находится в WEB-INF

Comment: Значит у вас что-то есть в приложении, которое открывает файл изнутри. Без исходного кода это невозможно понять.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.